# Template fields mappings for nginx module with filebeat on kubernetes are not correctly loaded

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

I'm deploying filebeat in kubernetes using the k8s manifests from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/7.5/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml

The filebeat template is loaded into elasticsearch, but the mappings for nginx module are incomplete:

```
"nginx" : {
  "properties" : {
    "access" : {
      "properties" : {
        "geoip" : {
          "type" : "object"
        },
        "user_agent" : {
          "type" : "object"
        }
      }
    },
    "error" : {
      "properties" : {
        "connection_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Most of the nginx properties defined in the fields.yaml are aliases and none of the properties defined as an alias are getting their way into the filebeat template.

Is there something I'm missing as part of the filebeat configuration ?

I also tried with my custom fields.yaml where I replaced the aliases with their concrete definition and the elasticsearh loaded mapping looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up mounting my own fields.yml as a ConfigMap on the filebeat DaemonSet and replacing the alias fields with their concrete definition.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Elastic's Marcin Tojek in Elastic community thread "[Filebeat Filebeat versions from 7.0 - 7.8 fail to create alias field mappings for majority of modules](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-versions-from-7-0-7-8-fail-to-create-alias-field-mappings-for-majority-of-modules/242874/)" the Beats Platform Reference 7.8, chapter Upgrade, section [Upgrade from 6.x to 7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/upgrading-6-to-7.html) states the following:

> Starting with 7.0, the fields exported by Beats conform to the [Elastic Common Schema (ECS)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/1.5/index.html). Many of the exported fields have been renamed. See [Breaking changes in 7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/7.8/breaking-changes-7.0.html) for the full list of changed names.
>
> To help you transition to the new fields, we provide a compatibility layer in the form of ECS-compatible field aliases. To use the aliases, set the following option in the Beat’s configuration file before you upgrade the Elasticsearch index template to 7.0.
>
> `migration.6_to_7.enabled: true`
> The field aliases let you use 6.x dashboards and visualizations with indices created by Beats 7.0 or later. The aliases do **not** work with saved searches or with API calls that manipulate documents directly.

Note that as of 2020-07-29 neither the Filebeats Reference 7.8 chapter [Exported fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields.html) mentions this nor do the Filebeat modules' sections which still list all of the aliases which do not get created by default anymore on fresh installations unless explicitly enabling "`migration.6_to_7.enabled: true`".